# symfony2: error when rendering template - Object could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony

I have this simply controller:

```
class SearchController extends Controller{
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $search = new Search();
    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType(), $search);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('search'));
    }

    return $this->render('MyApplicationBundle:Search:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
}
```

this is the search entity:

```
class Search {
protected $query;

public function setQuery($query)
{
    $this->query = $query;
}

public function getQuery()
{
    return $this->query;
}
}
```

and this is my form:

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('query', 'text')
        ->add('search', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'search';
}
}
```

unfortunately when trying to render the form

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I got this error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class My\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Search could not be converted to string in

BTW, the rendering of just HTML works fine.

any idea? thanks for your help

SOLVED: I found a workaround changing how to render the form:

```
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-search'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.query, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control search-query'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: There is no error in your visible code. Are you sure it is happening because of form? What is your twig template code?

Comment: I edited to display the full template code. the strange thing is that with other entities it works (same template and almost same code)

Comment: Have you set the `data_class` attribute to the formtype? As described in the section Setting the data_class of the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes). BTW you can add the `__toString()` method to the entity to see what appen

Comment: ho I havent but I have other entities working in the same way. do you have an example on how to do that? thanks.

Comment: Your solution with `form_start()` does not answer the question "why?", though.

Comment: instead of editing your question with your solution, make an answer of it ;)

Comment: @Veve: I object, your honor, this is not an answer : ) It's alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found an answer to your question [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1548).

> the method inherited from `AbstractType` will create the name according
>   to the class name which will lead to `search`. But this will cause
>   issues when rendering as there is a block to render the type `search`
>   but for the core type. You should set the name explicitly by using a
>   name not used already (a good way is to prefix it by the alias of the
>   bundle)

So the issue could be in the name `search` itself. Try specifying different name then.

Answer (score 0):

Every form needs to know the name of the class that holds the underlying data, as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

You should add the following method to the `SearchType` class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyApplicationBundle\Entity\Search',
    ));
}
```

and remember to add the following `use` method:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
```

Hope this help

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. I found a workaround and I updated my question. thanks anyway

Comment: This is more of a recomendation in case of complex structure. Code above should work without it.